# How to manually create Expression<Func<T, T>> in HtmlHelper overloads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

I'm trying to create custom HTML helper with the following signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LookupDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TIdProperty, TDisplayProperty, TExpiredProperty, TListItem>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<TListItem> enumeratedItems,
    Expression<Func<TListItem, TIdProperty>> idProperty,
    Expression<Func<TListItem, TDisplayProperty>> displayProperty,
    Expression<Func<TListItem, TExpiredProperty>> expiredProperty,
        string css = null,
        string optionLabel = null,
        string id = null,
        object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    //building the html
}
```

It's currently called like this:

```
@Html.LookupDropDownListFor(model => model.PrimaryName.NameSuffixId, Model.C_NameSuffixLst, id => id.Id, disp => disp.Display, exp => exp.IsVisible, "", "col-md-8")
```

This works fine. However, now I want to create an overload that doesn't have the idProperty, displayProperty, and expiredProperty. It would need to use some defaults for the three.

So, I made this simplified overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LookupDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TListItem>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<TListItem> enumeratedItems,
    string css = null,
    string optionLabel = null,
    string id = null,
    object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        return LookupDropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, enumeratedItems, idProp => idProp.Id, disp => disp.Display, exp => exp.IsVisible, css, optionLabel, id, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

However, I'm getting an error on exp => exp.IsVisible:

```
'TListItem' does not contain a definition for IsVisible
```

At this point, where could it be inferring the type of TListItem from? Is this the proper way to go about making an overload for a custom HTML helper?

Comment: It isn't inferring any type.  That's why you can't use any properties.  If you want to use properties, you need to specify or constrain to an actual type.

Comment: There are three lambda expressions in the constructor. It is only throwing an error on *one* of them.